# Data Manipulation - Power Query

Tags: powerquery, data-manipulation

Relatively new to Power Query. How would one get "value" into the "False" position based on "TEST"?
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGLOS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to test one column, and place a result into a new column

Add Column ... Custom column ...

formula

```
= if [YourTestColumnName] = "TEST" then "FALSE" else null
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This gets me to current state of my table - but looking ot reference the value a couple of rows down. I've seen 'fill up' and 'fill down' options - but these require filtering and removal of data from what I gather.

Comment: Not sure why. Right-click column title then fill ... down